# How do I fix a crack in floor of my shower tray?

Tags: shower, crack

The support material on the floor of my shower tray has detached. A crack has appeared where the shower tray flexes. I need to fix the crack with very strong material as the tray flexes on use.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You need a new tray. Water, cracks & flexing make very poor bedfellows.

Comment: One repair of this kind of failure of fiberglass/epoxy tub/showers used to be to drill a hole or holes, deliver foam through the holes which hardens into support, then repair the hole. When we had our original plastic shower replaced 20 years ago I noticed the new tray had numerous supporting ribs. I thought this should be sufficient support on the slab, but the plumber insisted on using a bed of mortar which I agreed to. We have had no problems. Don't know if there is a repair for the type of plastic used in the OP's tray.

Comment: When you fit a new shower tray, make sure it has excessively adequate support.

Comment: What is the "support material" on the floor of your shower tray? Is it a mortar bed? Is it spray foam?

Comment: There are tapes and glues, some sold in the automotive market, boat repair, surfboard construction, etc that could provide a temporary fix that will eliminate or reduce leakage for a week or two while you figure out your plans to replace this. Repairing it properly will be difficult and unreliable, not worth the effort compared to replacing it.

Comment: I think some of these plastic trays have supporting ribs which the mfgr presents as adequate support without a mortar bed, but whether this is sufficient for longest life I have no idea. Forty or 50 years ago my parents' single unit fiberglass tub/shower (Kohler?) split because it had no support. My parents had a 1200 sqft house built by a reluctant builder of larger homes in New Iberia LA and I would bet my mother worked the builder on the price. He in turn probably squeezed his subs so I suspect no or insufficient mortar bed.

Comment: Can these trays be replaced without redoing the walls?